# Eclipse hangs when attaching debugger

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am running the eclipse in debuggable mode. I have entered the debuggable mode in `AndroidManifest.xml` as `true`. However Eclipse hangs while running in debuggable mode. I am running Eclipse 1.4.1 on Windows 7 64 bit with Android API level 16. What could be wrong?

1. I have tried to restart Eclipse.
2. Killed `adb32.exe` and then restarted Eclipse.
3. Checked everything in the debug configurations.

---

```
[2012-04-04 15:02:05 - Droid1] ------------------------------
[2012-04-04 15:02:05 - Droid1] Android Launch!
[2012-04-04 15:02:05 - Droid1] adb is running normally.
[2012-04-04 15:02:05 - Droid1] Performing com.androidbook.droid1.Droid1Activity activity launch
[2012-04-04 15:02:05 - Droid1] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AVD' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'
[2012-04-04 15:02:05 - Droid1] Uploading Droid1.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-04-04 15:02:06 - Droid1] Installing Droid1.apk...
[2012-04-04 15:02:38 - Droid1] Success!
[2012-04-04 15:02:38 - Droid1] Starting activity com.androidbook.droid1.Droid1Activity on device emulator-5554
[2012-04-04 15:02:41 - Droid1] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.androidbook.droid1/.Droid1Activity }
[2012-04-04 15:02:42 - Droid1] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.androidbook.droid1' on port 8615
```

Logcat output:

```
04-06 15:39:48.417: D/dalvikvm(547): GC_EXPLICIT freed 226K, 5% free 9501K/9927K, paused 70ms+23ms 
04-06 15:39:48.437: E/StrictMode(547): class com.android.development.DevelopmentSettings; instances=2; limit=1 
04-06 15:39:48.437: E/StrictMode(547): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class com.android.development.DevelopmentSettings; instances=2; limit=1 
04-06 15:39:48.437: E/StrictMode(547): at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1) 
04-06 15:40:01.927: D/AndroidRuntime(571): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<< 
04-06 15:40:01.927: D/AndroidRuntime(571): CheckJNI is ON 
04-06 15:40:01.927: D/AndroidRuntime(571): CheckJNI is ON 
04-06 15:40:03.516: D/AndroidRuntime(571): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm 
04-06 15:40:03.587: D/AndroidRuntime(571): Shutting down VM 
04-06 15:40:03.606: I/AndroidRuntime(571): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed 
04-06 15:40:03.606: D/dalvikvm(571): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 463K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms 
04-06 15:40:03.616: D/dalvikvm(571): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries 
04-06 15:40:04.886: D/AndroidRuntime(584): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<< 
04-06 15:40:06.836: D/dalvikvm(584): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
```

Comment: it freezes when it says it is attaching the debugger on the console window? try to reboot your computer just to make sure all services and adb is actually rebooted and if it still get stuck consider re installing eclipse .. its just doesn't sound like any known eclipse problem..

Comment: ive tried restarting my laptop

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to have anything in your manifest file for debugging. Make sure you have all the necessary support for the API level you're running and that you have a correctly configured AVD that will run that API level.

Right click on the project and choose Debug As -> Android Application.

What Happens? If it is not opening in Debug mode you should at least see something in the console... error's, exceptions.. What do they say?

Comment: i believe its necessary to set the debuggable mode as true

Comment: I've worked in Eclipse/Android for almost two years and have never had any entry in any manifest xml file for debugging, none. Try to open the Debug perspective before launching in debug mode. That way you may  be able to see Logcat messages. What kind of laptop?? how much memory and what CPU? Next I would try to go down an API level to maybe 2.3. I say that because the emulator runs faster and leaner in earlier API's.

Comment: ive tried reinstalling eclipse helios that is IDE for java developers but the problem doesnt go away

Comment: here's the relevant logcat entries

Comment: 04-06 15:39:48.417: D/dalvikvm(547): GC_EXPLICIT freed 226K, 5% free 9501K/9927K, paused 70ms+23ms
04-06 15:39:48.437: E/StrictMode(547): class com.android.development.DevelopmentSettings; instances=2; limit=1
04-06 15:39:48.437: E/StrictMode(547): android.os.StrictMode$InstanceCountViolation: class

Comment: com.android.development.DevelopmentSettings; instances=2; limit=1
04-06 15:39:48.437: E/StrictMode(547):  at android.os.StrictMode.setClassInstanceLimit(StrictMode.java:1)
04-06 15:40:01.927: D/AndroidRuntime(571): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-06 15:40:01.927: D/AndroidRuntime(571): CheckJNI is ON

Comment: 04-06 15:40:01.927: D/AndroidRuntime(571): CheckJNI is ON
04-06 15:40:03.516: D/AndroidRuntime(571): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
04-06 15:40:03.587: D/AndroidRuntime(571): Shutting down VM
04-06 15:40:03.606: I/AndroidRuntime(571): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
04-06 15:40:03.606: D/dalvikvm(571): GC_CONCURRENT freed 101K, 78% free 463K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms

Comment: 04-06 15:40:03.616: D/dalvikvm(571): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
04-06 15:40:04.886: D/AndroidRuntime(584): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
04-06 15:40:06.836: D/dalvikvm(584): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries

Comment: please have a look at the logcat and help me out

Comment: I reformatted your logcat into your original message. Please delete the multiple comments. I am looking into this since I am curious, do you have any other info.

Comment: well it not exactly hangs i can continue my work but there is nothing in ddms

Comment: what do you get when you phone is plugged into usb and you type ddms? You should get the Dalvik Debug Monitor up with ylour phone connected. If not it sounds like you may need to set up some Path variables.